# R: identifying cases where the row contains more than one character from a list

Tags: r

I'm working on a large dataset where I need to create a new column and assign appropriate labels. So for instance, I have rows containing a mixture of fruits and vegetables, and I want a new column where it identifies the row as fruit, vegetable, or mixed. An ideal outcome is:

```
#     name   type
# 1    apple fruit
# 2    bananas fruit
# 3    kale   vegetable
# 4    apple, kale   mixed
```

While I'm successful at identifying types for rows containing single "items", I'm having trouble coding for "mixed" type. I was thinking of using AND (for example, mixed = fruit AND vegetable).. but this didn't work. Is there an efficient/correct way to coding for mixed instances? I appreciate your help, thank you!!

So right now what I have is:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('apple','bananas','kale','apple, kale'), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$type <- factor(df$name) # First step: copy vector and make it factor

#Change levels:
levels(df$type) <- list(
    fruit = c("apple", "bananas"),
    vegetable = c("kale")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `purrr` and `dplyr` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

l <- list(
  fruit = c("apple", "bananas"),
  vegetable = c("kale")
)

v <- unlist(l)
nm <- gsub("\\d", "", setNames(names(v), v))

df %>%
  mutate(type = map_chr(strsplit(name, ", "), ~ if (n_distinct(nm[.x]) > 1) "mixed" else nm[.x]))
```

**Output**

```
         name      type
1       apple     fruit
2     bananas     fruit
3        kale vegetable
4 apple, kale     mixed
```

**How it works**

1. Create a named vector to help translate `name` into `type`. For example, `nm["apple"]` returns `fruit`.
2. Then we split `name` into a list:

```
strsplit(df$name, ", ")
[[1]]
[1] "apple"

[[2]]
[1] "bananas"

[[3]]
[1] "kale"

[[4]]
[1] "apple" "kale"
```

3. Lastly, we map a `purrr` style function over this list. If the number of unique types returned is greater than one the value is `mixed`, otherwise we return the value from the named vector `nm`.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for quick response and detailed explanations. this is amazing. when I tried this, I'm getting an error message, because name is character and not string (" `type = map_chr(...)`.
x Result 6 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 3
i The error occurred in group 1: name = "Apple".) so I used toString to convert the column from character to string, it gets messed up completely (showing weird names). is there a way to tackle this error message?

Comment: @send_help you are welcome! It would be helpful if you could post an example where I can reproduce your issue. Does this code work for you on the example you have posted?